# How to get rid of (one) unnecessary copy when constructing a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, temporary-objects

I have a `class A` which handles my resources (quite large). Now I need a vector of these `std::vector<A> vec_of_A (3, A(int N))`. Problem is that `vector` first constructs temporary object `A(int N)`, then copy constructs from that three times and then destroys that temporary object. As my `A(int N)` allocates quite a large chunk of memory I end up (temporarily) with memory requirements 33% larger than I actually need.

How to construct `vector` of `A` while avoiding unnecessary constructors? (My `class A` satisfies all rules of five).

**EDIT:** Sorry I didn't realize the importance of default constructed object `A`. My question is **not** about default constructor but parametrizied constructor.

Comment: You can always store A* in the data structure.

Comment: Is your code snippet indicative? Are you default constructing the `A` argument?

Comment: @PhilipBrack That's [ahem] pointless if there's no specific reason to use a pointer. If value semantics work for the OP, there's no use putting things through an extra layer of overhead for (more) dynamic allocation and indirection. And the pointed-to `A`s would still need to be constructed, after all...

Comment: I wish people would stay online for a couple of minutes after posting to give clarifications. Three very good answers posted that may be invalidated in a second by a belated "no".

Comment: @StoryTeller aaaand there they go. Well NathanOliver *did* take care to cover all cases, so that's just fair :)

Comment: @Quentin - I'm still peeved over the principle of it all. I had a feeling this may be the case, and that's why I asked for the clarification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just want to default construct the objects in the vector you can just use

```
std::vector<A> vec_of_A(some_number);
```

That will create `some_number` default items.

If the items are not default constructable then `reserve` the space that you need and then use `emplace_back` to constructs the elements in place.  that looks like

```
std::vector<A> vec_of_A;
vec_of_A.reserve(some_number);
for (int i = 0; i < some_number; ++i)
    vec_of_A.emplace_back(/*constructor parameter(s) here */); // construct an object
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`std::vector::resize()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) method to fill the vector with 3 default-constructed items that do not need to be copied from an initial temp object:

```
std::vector<A> vec_of_A;
vec_of_A.resize(3);
```